# Aplicação em Python, PyQt5, não apresentando o arquivo .UI?

Tags: python, pyqt-5, software

Esse programa é uma aplicação para fazer download de videos do youtube, o código está funcionando, mas quando tentei chamar a interface gráfica criada no Qt Designer, ela não apareceu.

O código não apresentou nenhum erro, mas também não tá chamando a imagem.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por gentileza?

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

def funcao_principal():
    linha1 = Login.lineEdit.text()
    
    if Login.radioButton.isChecked():
        print("Música selecionada")
    elif Login.radioButton_2.isChecked():
         print("Vídeo selecionado")

    print("ENSIRA UM LINK:", linha1)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
Login = uic.loadUi("Login.ui")
Login.pushButton_login.clicked.connect(funcao_principal)


app.exec()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não consegue mostrar mais coisa? por exemplo, sua funcao_principal tem a linha1 dizendo q é uma linha de edição mas não especifica o nome do objeto, tamanho, posição dentro da janela...

Comment: Isso é o de menos... vc está mostrando a tela em preview no QT designer, mas salvou? vc precisa de um arquivo ou um template pra conseguir incorporar no teu programa. Se já tiver feito, coloca o código dele aqui pra gente

Comment: A resposta se encontra logo abaixo Karllos, espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Caraca deu certo, muito obrigado cara

Answer (score -1):

Todo o código permanece correto, porém, uma parte fundamental é chamar a tela que você configurou para poder interagir com ela, como função simples que traduzida do inglês significa **mostrar** a função ****.show**** irá lhe apresentar a tela, agora basta implementar.

Veja mais em [riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/](https://riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/) aqui tem a versão mais atual da biblioteca PyQt5.

```py
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets


def funcao_principal():
    linha1 = Login.lineEdit.text()

    if Login.radioButton.isChecked():
        print("Música selecionada")
    elif Login.radioButton_2.isChecked():

    print("INSIRA O LINK: ", linha1)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
Login = uic.loadUi("Login.ui")
Login.pushButton_login.clicked.connect(funcao_principal)

Login.show()  # Você esqueceu dessa etapa do código. Login.show() é o comando para a tela aparecer.
app.exec()
```